# Which.Max function

Tags: r, graph, axis, yaxis

```
N <- 300
N.2 <- 800
N.3 <- 600

change.y <- c(N, N.2, N.3)
use.y <- which.max(change.y)
graph.ylim <- use.y + 100
```

The output is [2], which is correct technically, but I want the output to say 800, not 2. Then, I want to plug in `use.y` as the `y-lim` here:

```
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0:300), ylim = c(150:900)) + 
  ...
```

Does anyone know how to do this? When I plug in `ylim = c(150:graph.ylim))`, my graph disappears.

Comment: You want `max`, not `which.max`.

Comment: I also recommend using `max()`. But if you insist on using `which.max()`, your penultimate line should be `use.y <- change.y[which.max(change.y)]`. The `which.max()` function returns an index, so it needs to be called in an object to reference a position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> change.y
[1] 300 800 600
> use.y <- max(change.y)
> use.y
[1] 800
```